# Correct terms of types in Java

Tags: java

Consider the following line of code:

```
java.lang.Number aNumber = new java.lang.Integer(1);
```

Now I am asking myself what would be the correct terms for both types (`Number`and `Integer`) regarding the variable `aNumber`?

Would you call `java.lang.Number` the "reference-type" and `java.lang.Integer` simply the "type"?!

I could not find any earlier threads regarding this issue..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A simple explanation would be `Integer` is the real type of the instance (instance type), `Number` is the visible type (reference type). Meaning that even if `aNumber` is an `Integer`, it will not be seen like it (unless you cast it)

Comment: `Number` is the super class of `Integer` , thus `Integer` is a type of `Number`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Number` is the static (or declared) type, `Integer` is the runtime (or dynamic, or actual) type.

The *variable* has type `Number`, the *instance* contained in the variable has type `Integer`.

A "reference type" is anything that inherits from `Object` (including arrays). The opposite are the "primitive types" (like `int`). Some languages also have "value types" (not Java, or maybe not yet).

Comment: Can you provide any JLS/other documentation links to support this? (Not saying you're wrong!)